# OTRS, SetPassword, No User Found

Tags: mysql, otrs

i installed OTRS6 and i'm trying to log in. In Debian i want to create new user and password in OTRS using otrs.Console.pl .
After create user i want to set the password using Admin::User::SetPassword ACCOUNT [PASSWORD] but i've got that error:

```
    ERROR: OTRS-otrs.Console.pl-Admin::User::SetPassword-10 Perl: 5.24.1 OS: linux Time: Sun Mar  4 16:41:12 2018

 Message: No Valid for valid found!

 Traceback (11786):
   Module: Kernel::System::Valid::ValidLookup Line: 139
   Module: Kernel::System::Valid::ValidIDsGet Line: 160
   Module: Kernel::System::User::UserSearch Line: 728
   Module: Kernel::System::Console::Command::Admin::User::SetPassword::Run Line: 47
   Module: (eval) Line: 460
   Module: Kernel::System::Console::BaseCommand::Execute Line: 454
   Module: Kernel::System::Console::InterfaceConsole::Run Line: 80
   Module: /opt/otrs/bin/otrs.Console.pl Line: 38

[Sun Mar  4 16:41:12 2018] otrs.Console.pl: DBD::mysql::st execute failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 2 at /opt/otrs/Kernel/System/DB.pm line 694.
ERROR: OTRS-otrs.Console.pl-Admin::User::SetPassword-10 Perl: 5.24.1 OS: linux Time: Sun Mar  4 16:41:12 2018

 Message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 2, SQL: 'SELECT id, login
                   FROM users WHERE  (login) LIKE ? AND valid_id IN ()'

 Traceback (11786):
   Module: Kernel::System::User::UserSearch Line: 737
   Module: Kernel::System::Console::Command::Admin::User::SetPassword::Run Line: 47
   Module: (eval) Line: 460
   Module: Kernel::System::Console::BaseCommand::Execute Line: 454
   Module: Kernel::System::Console::InterfaceConsole::Run Line: 80
   Module: /opt/otrs/bin/otrs.Console.pl Line: 38

Error: No user found with login 'admin@localhost'!
```

... on newly created account...

In MySQL database i see all users so they are exist.
Some help?

Answer (score 0):

In this case the contents of the `valid` table in the otrs database is empty; this might be because you have not loaded the `otrs-initial_insert.mysql.sql` file during setup. Typically this is performed by the web installer.

The best advise probably would be to drop your database and run the web installer again.